# Building mysql with readline instead of editline

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew, mysql

I'd really like to be able to use readline instead of editline with the mysql client, but I can't find out how to do this.

The *bottled* mysql that brew installs by default for mavericks is using editline.
There's no "readline" option in `brew options mysql` if I want to build if from source and it seems that I can't add this to the formula.

Has the readline support been dropped in mysql 5.6 ?
Should I use rlwrap as a workaround or is there a better way to do this ?

Thank you.

Comment: See [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/461916/48577) for an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is super old, but if you use [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com) instead it will be built with readline support. MariaDB is a fork of MySQL. `brew update && brew install mariadb`