# How can I use readline instead of editline in the Python REPL and other programs?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, homebrew, keybindings

I prefer to use [readline](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html) instead of [editline](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?editrc) in the Python REPL and MySQL for example. These programs are compiled with editline support as provided by Apple or Homebrew. How can I make them work with readline instead?

Answer (score 2):

From my GitHub Discussions [post](https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/4632):

### Use readline instead of editline (MacOS)

These instructions should work in other Unix-like/Linux OSes in addition to MacOS.

#### Disable editline

Edit `~/.editrc` and decide what to remove. Then add:

```
edit off
```

or prefix it with the application name or regex to limit which ones have editline disabled:

```
python3:edit off
```

The only line I previously had in that file was `bind -e` which I removed.

You can provide multiple prefixed lines (or an appropriate regex) to have the command apply to additional applications.

#### Install [`rlwrap`](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap)

```
brew install rlwrap
```

`rlwrap` has a bunch of options, see the output of:

```
rlwrap --help
```

or the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rlwrap).

#### Edit `~/.inputrc`

If you need to make any changes or additions to readline bindings you can edit this file. If you want to have configurations for particular programs wrap the settings in `$if` conditionals.

For system-global configuration, use `/etc/inputrc`. But note that a user-local configuration completely overrides the global one instead of being preferentially merged. However, you can include the global file (or others) using `$include`. Placement of those lines within a file controls precedence.

#### Create aliases

In your `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc` or other startup files (depending on how your shell is started), create aliases to make the use of `rlwrap` more convenient. For example:

```
alias python3='rlwrap python3'
```

I keep my aliases in a separate file and `source` them in my main startup file. I use `~/bin/aliases` but `~/.aliases` is another suggestion.

You can also run programs on an ad-hoc basis without an alias by prefixing the program name with `rlwrap` followed by a space (but without the surrounding quotes seen in the `alias` command).

#### Adjust your history files

For example, my Python history file was `~/.python_history` but the one created after using `rlwrap` is `~/.python3_history`. Instead of changing some configuration, I just renamed my old history so I could continue to use it:

```
mv ~/.python_history  ~/.python3_history
```

#### Enjoy!

<kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd><kbd>**r**</kbd>**your-previous-command**

#### And that's not all...

Try it with MySQL and others, too!